# Are multiple histories in a git repository likely to cause future issues?

Tags: git, github, git-filter-branch

I used `git filter-branch` to update a large number of commits in one of my repositories (correcting a author and committer email that was wrong). The command I used was:

```
git filter-branch -f --env-filter "GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL='mike.r.anderson.13@gmail.com'; GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL='mike.r.anderson.13@gmail.com';"
```

Followed by a git pull to sync with the remote repository

This worked fine, however when I look at the history in GitHub I see two complete histories, one before the change and one after the change. which eventually merge at a single point.

- https://github.com/mikera/vectorz/network (now fixed with a single history thanks to Will and Petr!)

Is this a problem? Or can I safely leave both histories there?

Comment: I see that you've added the `filter-branch` command, but that by itself wouldn't have caused the graph I'm seeing. Perhaps an additional command related to pushing into your repository? I suspect that you followed the often-used (and very wrong) practice of typing `git pull` whenever a `push` responds with a "[rejected] ... non-fastforward" error. Is this the case?

Comment: @Will - you may well be right, I think I may have pulled by mistake... which would have merged the two histories together? I take it I should force a push here instead?

Comment: correct, I'll update my answer to explain more-thoroughly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, `git filter-branch` is meant to rewrite history, not create a parallel history alongside another. If you've finished your `filter-branch` operation by merging, you've used it incorrectly.

This can indeed lead to confusion, as you may sometimes see one, sometimes the other, line of history. Any time you have multiple lines of history making the same change, it's a bad thing. Imagine operations such as `bisect` or `blame`, where you're trying to locate the commit which introduced a particular change. Now, there are often two historical commits which actually do the same thing- which one do you want?

Even basic operations like `git log`, when date-ordered, may show long runs of "duplicate" commits. Clearly not desired behaviour.

On a more idealogical note: Should you even be rewriting history to correct such a minor issue? git has a feature for this exact situation: "[mailmap](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog#_mapping_authors)".

You should generally avoid rewriting published history unless there is a security concern (that is: a disclosure problem... and even then, once a secret is out, it's best to invalidate the secret, rather than simply limiting its exposure, when possible), or a situation like this one, where some bad history has been published which has made the repository hard to use.

Note that running history-rewriting commands such as `filter-branch` or `rebase` on published history will make it so that git no longer considers your local commits to be "based on" the existing upstream commits. Due to this, pushing normally will result in an error such as:

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast forward)
```

So you will need to "force" the push, ie: `git push -f`. Standard caveats regarding `-f` apply (be sure not to clobber anyone else's commits), and of course, warnings about [rewriting public history](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_recovering_from_upstream_rebase).

Aside from those warnings regarding rewriting public history, then so long as you *actually rewrite*, not create parallel histories, then there's no need for concern. Let's just go over a summary of the main potential issues, for completeness:

- Anyone with an existing copy, who does not rebase to your new history before pushing, will receive the "non-fast forward" warning, and may assume that they need to merge.
- Anyone who merges the old history with the new, and pushes, will cause the "old" history to be restored.
- Old references in mailing lists, emails, etc, to commit ids from the "old" history will no-longer be relevant.

Due to the third point, I recommend keeping a tag alive of the "old" history, so that any historical discussions which mention commit-ids will still point somewhere valid. Do name the tag with something which makes it obvious that the tag is *not* to be used for new development, however.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for starters, you will still have commits with the wrong committed email in your history, so did you really gain anything? :-)

Other than that, I think it will be mainly confusing to *users* rather than *tools*, which may be even worse situation. Whichever commit e.g. `git blame` will pick is bound to be fairly random, most likely depending on the first parent of the merge commit...

Generally, any kind of history browsing is going to be painful - for you, not for the tools. So it is a good idea to repair this now in some way, because repairing it is going to be only more difficult as time goes on.

Comment: Makes sense.... but then how is best to fix this? Was `git filter-branch` the wrong tool for this job? Or should I use some other tool afterwards to delete the old history?

Comment: `git filter-branch` is the correct tool. First, use `git reset --hard COMMITNAME` to force-rewind your local history to before the merge. Then, just push this commit to the server = use `git push --force` to overwrite the server history.